# HTML Form: 2 Actions 1 Submit button

Tags: php, html, forms, cgi, action

I was just wondering how to run 2 different actions from 1 submit button. The reason I ask this, is I have a file upload script which I installed to the page, which is a `.cgi` file. I need to run a `.php` as well so that I can submit to a database and send an email, is there anyway that I can do this?

To sum it up quite quickly, what I am looking for is something that will do this: (I know this won't work, just for principal)

`<form action="email.php upload.cgi" method="post">` This is a simplified version of my form I have other parameters and such for the form.

Comment: Just have one url to do both tasks.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I need help doing... The cgi is already setup and I was going to write the php... Any way I can do it in whatever language cgi is in?

Answer (score 0):

Can you have 2 actions for 1 form?

The answer is...No.
A form must have exactly one action. However, the server-side (e.g., CGI) program that processes your form submissions can perform any number of tasks (e.g., updating a database, sending email, logging a transaction) in response to a single form submission.

One way around this would be to use JavaScript ( or jQuery ) to submit the form, but of course you will have to consider this twice before doing it.